# Слетает авторизация Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, сессия, auth

Хочу сделать так что бы авторизация держалась бесконечно.
вот код модели авторизации LoginForm

```
 public function login()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), 0);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Я так полагаю что второй параметр duration это как раз время сессии, и если правильно понял то 0 - это бесконечно.
в конфиге вот такие настройки

```
 'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
```

Однако по истечению какого то времени авторизация слетает. В чем может быть дело?
UPD Сессию нигде не закрываю.. Но возможны повторные открывания сессий по коду. Может быть дело в этом?

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте в массив `user` ключ `authTimeout` и уберите `enableAutoLogin=>false`

```
'user' => [
      'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
      'authTimeout' => 60 * 60 * 24 * 100, //100 дней для примера
],
```

**P.S.** Важно знать, что данный ключ будет работать только если `enableAutoLogin=>false`.

[Подробно про authTimeout](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#$authTimeout-detail)

Comment: а что надо прописать что бы это было бесконечно?

Comment: Поправил. Это могли бы уже и сами сделать...

Comment: Я так полагаю что дело было в php.ini , там есть параметр session.gc_maxlifetime

Comment: Данный ответ считается работоспособным в том, случае когда сам php.ini у вас настроен правильно, то есть если у вас session.gc_maxlifetime = 10 секунд, то что бы вы не делали - срок жизни сессии будет равен 10 секундам.

Comment: а если поставить 0 то это будет считаться бесконечностью?

Comment: Если session.gc_maxlifetime = 0, то сессия будет работать до тех пор, пока Вы не закроете браузер. Если такой вариант устроит, то пользуйтесь)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте компонент User в web.php (basic Yii2)

```
'user' => [
    'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity', 'httpOnly' => true]
],
```

Затем перейдите в модуль User (app\models\User) и замените функцию findIdentity на:

```
public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    return static::findOne($id);
}
```